# How to set default JDK Compliance level and release enabled in eclipse JDK preferences section

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde, pdebuild

I want to perform a PDE build for my RCP product. I am compiling my product with JDK 11 but I want to set --release option as 1.8. I wanted to know how we can provide a default compliance setting in eclipse. So I can build my product with eclipse settings.

[image]

I want to set --release option as 8. But we can't add release option to `<java />` tag. So I need to set a compliance level as 1.8 (by default) in JDT preferences.

**Can anyone answer how we can set default compliance level and enable --release option in eclipse?**

The eclipse version is 4.12 and I want to set release option as 8 for PDE build.

**What all the options I have tried**

1. Set compliance level to 1.8 but it is setting for particular workspace. It is not setting for default.
2. I have copied `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` from workspace to *\eclipse\configuration.settings*
3. Provided javacSource & javacTarget (But here we need to provide --release value)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the project (_Project > Properties: Java Compiler_) set the _Compiler compliance level_ to 8. By the way, your Eclipse is pretty old. You are 4 releases behind. Please upgrade.

Comment: I know how to set compliance level. But the thing is I need to set it for all workspace.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me. Please describe the problem with a reproducible example, including what you are actually getting and what you expect to get. Note that PDE build is deprecated and Tycho is now the standard for building RCP applications.

Comment: If we set compliance level 1.8 and then if we reopen eclipse with different workspace, it will change the compliance level to 11 (11 is installed). I want it same for all workspace.

Comment: To share preferences accross workspaces, use the _Preference Recorder_ which can be enabled in _Window > Preferences: Oomph > Setup Tasks > Preference Recorder_.

Comment: I am not able to find _Window > Preferences: Oomph > Setup Tasks > Preference Recorder_  (I have installed the Oomph)

Comment: Oomph is a project that provides different things, e.g. the _Eclipse Installer_, the _Preference Recorder_ and other things. You've updated your Eclipse in the meantime, right? Which IDE package do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse works on workspace level. So all the configuration are stored in workspace.
Project > Properties: Java Compiler will set the java compiler version to one particular version for a workspace.
You may not be able to set it for all workspace in one shot in Eclipse.

I would suggest the following

1. set JDK_HOME environment variable to required version of Java
2. Place required Java version  path to PATH variable in the begining.

then start eclipse and check.

Comment: you are right, all the configuration is stored in the workspace. I tried your suggestion but didn't work. It is still showing the 11 instead of 1.8 (JDK_HOME).

Comment: can you check eclipse.ini file? and also in command prompt what is the java version you are getting?